# Flash cs6 publishing to ipad with low quality

Tags: flash

I am using Flash CS6 and publishing with air 3.2 for ios.  My stage is 1024 x 768 and I am transferring my .api file to an ipad 2 using itunes.  When I launch the file on the Ipad the entire image looks pixelated/low quality.  However the entire app was created in Illustrator so its all vector.  The app also does not full screen to landscape but rather shrinks to fit in portrait mode.  My air settings are as follows:

GENERAL
Aspect Ratio: Landscape
Render mode: Auto
Device: Ipad
Resolution: High
Included files: a 1024 x 768 black file named Default-Landscape.png

DEPLOYMENT
Quick Publishing for device testing
I've also tried Deployment - Ad hoc

**TroubleShooting:**
- Created a new app at 2048 x 1536 - still pixelated not rotating
- Published to air 4.0 but displayed all white on Ipad
- I've also rotated my design to display on its side in portrait mode and it came out full screen but still pixelated.

Would really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Try using standard insted of High, ind the resolution settings...

I have a simular problem. My iPad 3 installs properly but the iPad 2 does not. The installation gets through using iTunes, but the installation never gets done?